# Itô's formula application

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

This exercise is from **M.Jeanblanc's**   *Stochastic calculus exercises*.

Let
$$ X_t=(1-t)\int_{0}^{t}{\frac{dB_s}{1-s}}\hspace{0.6cm}, 0\leq t<1$$

We want to calculate $dX_t$.

**My approach** : If we consider
$$f(X,Y)=(1-X)Y$$
and
$$Y_t=\int_{0}^{t}{\frac{dB_s}{1-s}}\implies dY_t=\frac{dB_t}{1-t}$$
we'll get using the formula
$$df=f_{X}dX + f_{Y}dY +\frac{1}{2}f_{XX}dX^2 +\frac{1}{2}f_{YY}dY^2 +f_{XY}dXdY$$
$$\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
&f_{X}dX=-YdX\\
&f_{Y}dY=(1-X)dY\\
&\frac{1}{2}f_{XX}dX^2=0\\
&\frac{1}{2}f_{YY}dY^2=0\\
&f_{XY}dXdY=-dXdY\\
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$$
By considering $X_t=f(t,Y_t)$ we get
$$ dX_t=(-dt)\int_{0}^{t}{\frac{dB_s}{1-s}}+(1-t)\frac{dB_t}{1-t}-dt\frac{dB_t}{1-t}$$

The answer in the reference doesn't have the last term $$dt\frac{dB_t}{1-t}$$

Am I working with a wrong formula or did I miss something ?

Comment: Everything is right, this term is zero.

Comment: How is it equal to zero zero ?

Comment: "Rules for multiplying differentials": $dt\cdot dt = dt\cdot dB_t = dB_t\cdot dt = 0; dB_t \cdot dB_t = dt$.

Comment: @zhoraster I'll need to take a look at these properties. Is there, by any chance, a good reference in which these are explained in detail ?

Comment: Any textbook in stochastic analysis. For example, Oksendal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression $dtdB_t$ is short notation for the quadratic variation process. Check the definition and apply it to the processes $\{t\}$ and $\{B_t\}.$ You will see you get zero.

(I don't have enough reputation for a comment)

Comment: Thank you ! I'll check the definition.